# how to sort select option in lexical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

i have a select option

```
<select>
<option>aaa</option>
<option>ccc</option>
<option>ddd</option>
<option>bbb</option>
</select>
```

How to sort them. 
so output will

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

this question is asked to me in an interview
answer if any Know Thanks In advance

Comment: Try [**this jQuery Plugin**](https://github.com/GodsBest/sortSelect)

Comment: Thanks .......may it was an duplicate question but i really don't know the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use use JavaScript sort method. It sorts the elements in lexical order. So you can set the innerHTML of the `select` element based on the result of the sort function.

Read more about the sort function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Try:

```
$("select").html($('select option').sort(function (x, y) {

    return $(x).text() < $(y).text() ? -1 : 1;

}))
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N2kW2/1/)

Comment: can u please explain it to me

Comment: In case anyone has options that look like "20 people", "5 people" and want to properly sort them (the "2" from "20" will come before "5") you can use `return parseInt($(x).text().split(' ')[0]) < parseInt($(y).text().split(' ')[0]) ? -1 : 1;` and "5 people" will come before "20 people".

Answer (score 0):

Add an id

```
<select id='myselect'>
<option>aaa</option>
<option>ccc</option>
<option>ddd</option>
<option>bbb</option>
</select>
```

Get all options in an array, sort it and then change the values of the select

```
var array = new Array();
$("#myselect option").each(function() { array.push($(this).text()) });
array.sort();

$("#myselect option").each(function(index,elem) { $(this).html(array[index]) });
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aPrUN/6/)

```
$('#sort').click(function () {
$('select').each(function () {
   var options = $(this).children('option');
    options.sort(function (optionA, optionB) {
        return optionA.value.localeCompare(optionB.value);
    });
    $(this).empty().append(options);
});
});
```